# Error: Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test

Tags: angular, jasmine, webpack, karma-jasmine, angular2-template

I'm getting this error:

> Error: This test module uses the component MessagesComponent which is using a "templateUrl", but they were never compiled. Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test.

When trying to run this simple test Angular 2 & Jasmine Test:

```
  let comp:    MessagesComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MessagesComponent>;

describe('MessagesComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {


        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ MessagesComponent ],
            providers:    [ {provide: DataService, useValue: {} } ]

        })
            .compileComponents(); // compile template and css

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MessagesComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;

    });

    it('example', () => {
        expect("true").toEqual("true");
    });
});
```

I think it might be due to something with my webpack test configuration:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { loader: 'raw', test: /\.(css|html)$/ },
            { exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'ts', test: /\.ts$/ }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts'],
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        root: path.resolve('.', 'src')
    },
    tslint: {
        emitErrors: true
    }
};
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Template fetching is asynchronous when your templates are not inlined into your components, so you need to tell Jasmine that. Change

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ ... })
        .compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MessagesComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
});
```

to

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ ... })
        .compileComponents()
        .then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MessagesComponent);
            comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        });
}));
```

Comment: should I change the it(...) method in any way?

Comment: Only if the `it()` does anything asynchronously, for example, if it fetches data from a service. It's totally okay if the the `beforeEach()` needs to be asynchronous but the `it()` does not.

Comment: weird I asked because I keep gettin the same error message as posted in my original question but at least now it says 1 of 1 failed

Comment: Oh, I missed something: `...compileComponents().then(() => { ... })` and create your component inside that function. You're creating the component before the template is loaded and compiled.

Comment: please post the code complete how it should be I really don't understand

Comment: On mobile. Will modify my answer tonight.

Comment: please don't forget about this :)

Answer (score 5):

Since you are already using `webpack`, theoretically you should not have to call the `compileComponents()` function according to the official doc [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#compilecomponents),  because `webpack` inlines templates and css as part of the automated build process that precedes running the test.

One possible reason that your template/css are not inlined is the IDE(`VisualStudio/WebStorm/IntelliJ`) auto compiles your ts to js and the webpack loaders which target for `js/ts` files are trying to get applied on the **already compiled js** files instead of the source ts files.