# Jasmine test for simple Angular2 component not working

Tags: angular, jasmine, webpack, karma-jasmine, angular2-template

I have this simple component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'messages',
    styleUrls: ['messages.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: 'messages.component.html',
})
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

    public getOne(): number{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to run a test for it but I can't get it to work please help:

```
describe('Component: MessagesComponent', () => {
    let component: MessagesComponent;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [MessagesComponent],
        }).compileComponents();

        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MessagesComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should have a defined component', () => {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

(I'm using webpack if that is relevant)

This is the error I get:

```
    Error: This test module uses the component MessagesComponent
 which is using a "templateUrl", but they were never compiled.
 Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: This test module uses the component MessagesComponent
>   which is using a "templateUrl", but they were never compiled.
>   Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test.

When using Webpack, you shouldn't need to compile your components (with `templateUrl`). The templateUrl's should get converted to inline `template`s when you use the `angular2-template-loader`.

See the [`webpack.test.js`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#test-configuration) example from the Angular docs. You will need to make sure you have the dependency for the loader. I would imagine you should already have it to be used for the main project though

```
"devDepdendencies": {
  "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
}
```

If you're still confused about the single config file I linked to above, you might just want to read the entire [Angular docs on webpack](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html). Shouldn't take that long. But it will walk you through getting set up for both the main application and the tests.

Also looking at your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40432734/2587435), your webpack config doesn't have any sass support either. I imagine this is something that you have configured in the main application webpack config. You can look at that to see how it is configured. Or you can check [this out](https://github.com/psamsotha/angular2-webpack). It's basically a project I put together from the Angular docs, just as a reference with everything in one place. The Angular docs doesn't add any sass support, but the linked project does add it.

Answer (score 1):

You get this test failure message when the runtime environment compiles the source code during the tests themselves.

To correct the problem, call compileComponents() as explained below.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ YourComponent ],
  })
  .compileComponents()
  .then(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
}));
```

here we must call compileComponents() with async function and then create a component instance in 'then block', this will solve the problem.

refer https://angular.io/guide/testing#compile-components for more information.